# how to get record from 'and' operation with 'in' and is null clause

Tags: mysql

how do i get record which is containing both null value and some value using 'and' operation between 'in' and 'is null' clause in mysql query?

query:
`select * from table1 where column in (value1,value2) or column is null;(works fine).` 
but when i use `and` instead of `or` I am getting empty set;

Comment: a value can't be both `null` and not null. Could you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? It would make the question much clearer.

Comment: the query which i am trying to run is:select * from table where column1 in (value1,value2) and column1 is null which results in empty set.while the query select * from table where column1 in (value1,value2) or column1 is null works fine

Comment: Also, please show some data which demonstrates your problem.  I can imagine you having this issue when aggregating over several records, but with a single record it makes no sense.

Comment: Please post your table structure and expected output of query.

Comment: select * from student where student_name in('jake','will') or student_name is null gives record containg both null along with the record mentioned in 'in' clause.                                              But when use :select * from student where student_name in ('jake','will') and student_name is null; returns empty set.

Comment: +-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| survey_id | question_id | answer_id | answer |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+
|         1 |           2 |         1 | gad    |
|         2 |           2 |         2 | great  |
|         4 |           2 |         3 | NULL   |
|         5 |           2 |         5 | NULL   |
|         1 |           2 |         6 | gae    |
|         6 |           2 |         7 | good   |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+table being in use

Comment: query that is working,select * from answers where answer in ('gae','gad') or answer is null;
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| survey_id | question_id | answer_id | answer |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+
|         1 |           2 |         1 | gad    |
|         4 |           2 |         3 | NULL   |
|         5 |           2 |         5 | NULL   |
|         1 |           2 |         6 | gae    |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+

Comment: query that I am trying to run :select * from answers where answer in ('gae','gad') and answer is null;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

The conditions in the WHERE clause are applied to each row.

```
 FROM bar WHERE foo IN ('a','b','c') AND foo IS NULL
```

is guaranteed to never evaluate to TRUE for any row in `bar`.  A row has a *single* value for column `foo`. That value can be `NULL`, or it can be non-NULL, one or the other.  The value of `foo` cannot be NULL and non-NULL at the same time, when the conditions are being evaluated.

By definition,  `WHERE foo IS NOT NULL AND foo IS NULL` will never evaluate to true. We are guaranteed that there are no rows that satisfy that condition.